# Is there a learning Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am specifically looking for a site where I can get answers or share knowledge about how people learn things. What works and what doesn't.

An example would be where a person asks questions about types of learning, or how people learn a certain type of material more quickly or retention of material, etc.

It may involve a great many disciplines and is briefly outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science#Learning_and_development) in the context of cognitive science.

I additionally searched for a cognitive science Stack Exchange site, but I had no success.

Comment: Academia maybe?

Comment: There is a [cogsci.se] site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* a Cognitive Science Stack Exchange, but it has [recently been renamed](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2301/14337) to [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/). The old URL, http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/ still works, and if you use the search function of the Stack Exchange menu, you'll still get a hit:

[image]

This site has (at the moment of writing) 307 questions tagged [[learning]](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), so your question might have already been asked

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Language Learning.SE](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com) site. This site allows questions about techniques for learning and teaching languages. Questions about memorization techniqes, study groups, finding a tutor, evaluating curricula, and similar are on-topic.

Comment: I don't think the question is limited to learning of languages...

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser my answer was meant to compliment the other answer.